# Metagene analysis with deepTools; 5UTR-CDS-3UTR and Exon-Intron-Exon

Tags: chip-seq, deeptools

I have some [PCR-CLIP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5142217/) data. PAR-CLIP identifies targets for RNA binding proteins. I am interested to build metagene profile so that transcript wide binding pattern can be compared. What I am mostly interested to plot:

1. 5UTR-CDS-3UTR
2. Exon-Intron-Exon

With deepTools I can make a combined profile where metagene profile for whole transcript length is found.

For 5UTR-CDS-3UTR, what I did:

- create bigwig files (from bam files) for signal
- used GTF as region of interest

The code goes as follows:

```
computeMatrix scale-regions
--metagene
-m 1000
-S *bw
-R *gtf
-a 1000
-b 1000
--transcriptID transcript
--transcript_id_designator transcript_id
-o outMat.mtx

plotProfile -m outMat.mtx -out outFig.png --perGroup
```

Generated image, given below, where my understanding is

1. -1.0:TSS is 5' UTR,
2. TSS:TES is CDS+3'UTR

[image]

If that is so, I am missing 3' UTR region.
So what I did, running `computeMatrix reference-point` by centering at TSS, center and TES with +/- 1000bp. The plot is as follows:
[image]
With some operations I converted it to:

[image]

Beside this kind of manual fix, I believe there are some systematic way to render such metagene profile where 5UTR-CDS-3UTR would be side by side for comparison.

**1. For plotting such 5UTR-CDS-3UTR metagene profile systematically, how should I proceed with deepTools**

In addition to that if I am interested to plot such metagene profile for 5Exon-Intron-3Exon, like the example given below.
[image]

**2. For generating Exon-Intron-Exon metagene profile how could I proceed with deepTools?**